# Unable to assign getBytes() to byte array

Tags: java, arrays, assign

I'm completely stumped.. Seems like there'd be a simple solution

```
private Byte[] arrayOfBytes = null;    

public Data(String input) {
    arrayOfBytes = new Byte[input.getBytes().length];
    arrayOfBytes = input.getBytes();
}
```

Throws the follwing error:

```
incompatible types
    required: java.lang.Byte[]
    found: byte[]
```

Comment: Auto-boxing just handles the conversion of values not type casting

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getBytes()` from String returns a `byte[]` and you are trying to affect it to a `Byte[]`.

`byte` is a primitive whereas `Byte` is a wrapper class (kind of like Integer and int).

What you can do is change :

```
private Byte[] arrayOfBytes = null;
```

to :

```
private byte[] arrayOfBytes = null;
```

Answer (score 2):

So try:

```
private byte[] arrayOfBytes = null;    

public Data(String input) {
    arrayOfBytes = new byte[input.getBytes().length];
    arrayOfBytes = input.getBytes();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! But isn't this exactly what I wrote, line for line?

Comment: @marshmallow:  nope change `Byte` to `byte`.

Answer (score 2):

Byte is an Object, while byte is a primative.  Like the difference between Integer and int.

Answer (score 1):

[getBytes()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes%28%29) return a `byte[]` array. You are assigning to `Byte[]` array.

So, this should work

```
private byte[] arrayOfBytes = null;    

public Data(String input) {
    arrayOfBytes = new Byte[input.getBytes().length];
    arrayOfBytes = input.getBytes();
}
```

> The [Byte class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Byte.html) wraps a value of primitive type byte in an object. An
>   object of type Byte contains a single field whose type is byte.

Answer (score 1):

```
public Data(String input) {
    arrayOfBytes = new byte[input.getBytes().length];// this line is useless
    arrayOfBytes = input.getBytes();
}
```